# Is there are nice proof of showing that $ (-1)^k\frac{d^k}{dx^k } e^{-x^2} \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking for a nice trick to show that
\begin{align}
(-1)^k\frac{d^k}{dx^k } e^{-x^2} \ge 0, x>0
\end{align}

If one starts doing expansion than the expression, become very cumbersome and hard to use.

Comment: maybe try induction?

Comment: @Airdish Can you scetch a proof for me? I would fill in the gaps.

Comment: Is that even true? $e^{-x^2}$ starts concave-down and becomes concave-up. Hence the second derivative changes sign in $(0,\infty)$

Comment: The second derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ is $f''(x) = (4x^2-2)e^{-x^2}$. Take $x \in (0,1/2)$...